# How do I search for an Exact phrase in Solr

Tags: solr, opentext

How do I search for an exact phrase in solr. Suppose, when I search for "How_to_Search_this" then it should give me the results of
1. "how_to_search_this" (case insensitive)
2. "How_to_search_this"

but not the results like
1. "How_to_search_this_thing"
2. "How_to_search_**that_thing**"

Please help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do only get exact, lowercase hits, use a KeywordTokenizer. KeywordTokenizer keeps the input string as a single token, but while `string` does the same, `KeywordTokenizer` allows you to attach filters as well.

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>           
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This will only give you hits when the query value is identical to the indexed value, except for case.

Comment: Actually, I already am using the solr.NGramTokenizerFactory tokenizer. I need it for other requirements. Can we not implement the **Exact phrase search** using this tokenizer?

Comment: Use different fields for different needs and use cases. An NgramTokenizer will not be suitable for exact phrase search, since it'll generate _many_ tokens for each term. Use `copyField` to index the same content into multiple fields.